# Differences between different .net framework HtmlEncode methods

Tags: asp.net, .net

What differences, if any are there between:

[System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode(v=vs.110).aspx)
[System.Web.HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode(v=vs.110).aspx)
[System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388364(v=vs.110).aspx)

Both HttpUtility.HtmlEncode and HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode say:

> To encode or decode values outside of a web application, use the [WebUtility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Which implies that there is a difference, but doesn't come out say so directly or say what the difference is, if there is one.

Comment: Why don't you check the source code? .Net is [open source these days.](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/)

Comment: basically if you dont want to include `System.Web` as a reference and keep a client profile

Comment: @Liam: two reasons.  I'm not used to thinking of the .net source as being available, and I think it makes a good question.  So, despite the downvote, I'm not deleting it.  Particularly after the great answer it got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dig though the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com) you can follow easily enough.

### System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode

```
    /// <devdoc>
    ///    <para>
    ///       HTML encodes a string and returns the encoded string.
    ///    </para>
    /// </devdoc>
    public static String HtmlEncode(String s) {
        return HttpEncoder.Current.HtmlEncode(s);
    }
```

### System.Web.HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode

```
    /// <devdoc>
    ///    <para>
    ///       HTML
    ///       encodes a given string and
    ///       returns the encoded string.
    ///    </para>
    /// </devdoc>
    public string HtmlEncode(string s) {
        return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s);
    }
```

### System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode

```
    public static string HtmlEncode(string value) {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
            return value;
        }

        // Don't create string writer if we don't have nothing to encode
        int index = IndexOfHtmlEncodingChars(value, 0);
        if (index == -1) {
            return value;
        }

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        HtmlEncode(value, writer);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
```

So `System.Web.HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode` actually uses `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`. If you drill into `HttpEncoder.Current.HtmlEncode(s);` this has the following code:

```
    protected internal virtual void HtmlDecode(string value, TextWriter output) {
        WebUtility.HtmlDecode(value, output);
    }
```

### Tl;Dr

So they all, *ultimately*, use `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode`. I guess the `System.Web` version are only there for backwards compatibillity. Hence the advice of using the `System.Net` version.

Comment: Great answer.  I notice that HttpUtility.Htmlencode has the possibility of a different (non-default) encoder. Hopefully IIS doesn't create one.